# Searching terms with numbers and underscores with Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Django Haystack with Elasticsearch. I have a bunch of items with a field called 'name' in this type of format:

> PA_Team1_01_00001

I would like to be able to search

> pa_team1

And get as a result

> pa_team1_01_00001
>
> pa_team1_01_11111
>
> pa_team1_11_00000
>
> ...

and so on.

From what I've read, this should be easily done with an EdgeNgramField, however when I search for this term I get no results. Here is what I have:

```
class FilesIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.NgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created')
    name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')

def get_model(self):
    return Files

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

and in the shell it only works when I enter the exact name, even though I have it specified as an EdgeNgram.

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> from drives.models import Files
>>> a = SearchQuerySet().models(Files).all()
>>> b = a.filter(name='pa_team1')
>>> b
[]
>>> b = a.filter(name='pa_team1_01_00001.txt')
>>> b
[<Files: PA_Team1_01_00001.txt>]
>>> b = a.filter(name='pa')
>>> b
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I've never used django-haystack, but shouldn't you use `autocomplete` instead of `filter`

I saw it [here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html#step-2-performing-the-query)

I guess you should do:

```
a = SearchQuerySet().models(Files).all()
# is '.all()' right?
b = a.automplete(name='pa_team1')
```

Let me know if that works.

Hope helps.